# Cannot convert value of type '[AnyObject]' to expected argument type '[UIUserNotificationAction]?'

Tags: swift

```
var category:UIMutableUserNotificationCategory=UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
category.identifier="DEFAULT_GATEGORY"
let defaultAction:NSArray=[action]
category.setActions(defaultAction as [AnyObject] as [AnyObject], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal)
```

Comment: What type is `action`?

Comment: @JefferyThomas UIMutableUserNotificationAction

Comment: It would be good if you explain your situation, what exactly your doing, what have you tried, etc. It help other users to help you :D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `action` is of  type `UIUserNotificationAction`:

```
var category = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory() // NOTE: type not needed.
category.identifier = "DEFAULT_GATEGORY"
let defaultAction = [action] // NOTE: Type not needed.
category.setActions(defaultAction, forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal)
```

---

As you can see, all I did was remove unneeded (and misleading) type information. I find it helpful to lean on Swift's auto type determination system.

---

Tested with the following Playground code:

```
let action = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
var category = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
category.identifier = "DEFAULT_GATEGORY"
let defaultAction = [action]
category.setActions(defaultAction, forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal)
```